# Error: Argument 20 matches multiple formal arguments in venn.diagram function

Tags: r, error-handling, venn-diagram

I'm very new to the `venn.diagram()` function, and am trying to create a simple venn diagram. Here is the data I am using:

```
structure(list(Transmitter = c("1657", "1657", "1658", "1659", 
"1659", "1660", "1660", "1661", "1662", "1663", "1663", "1664", 
"1664", "1666", "1667", "1667", "1668", "1668", "1669", "1670", 
"1671", "1671", "1672", "1672", "1673", "1673", "1674", "1674", 
"1675", "1675", "1676", "1676", "1678", "1679", "1679", "1680", 
"1681", "1681", "1682", "1682", "1683", "1684", "1685", "1686", 
"1686", "9782", "9782", "24166", "24166", "24167", "24168", "24169", 
"24170", "24171", "24172", "24173", "24174", "24175", "24175", 
"24176", "24177", "24178", "24179", "24179", "24180", "24181", 
"24182", "24183", "24184", "24184", "24185", "24186", "24187", 
"24188", "24189", "24190", "24191", "24192", "24193", "24194", 
"24194", "24195", "24195", "24196", "24197", "24198", "24198", 
"24199", "24199", "24200", "24201", "24203", "24204", "24204", 
"24206", "24207", "24209", "24210", "24211", "24212", "24212", 
"24213", "24214", "24215", "24216", "24216", "24217", "24218", 
"24219", "30759", "30760", "30761", "30761", "30761", "30762", 
"30763", "30764", "30765", "30765", "30765", "30766", "30766", 
"30766", "30767", "30767", "30768", "30768", "30768", "30769", 
"30769", "30769", "30770", "30771", "30772", "30772", "30772", 
"30773", "30773", "30773", "30774", "30774", "30775", "30775", 
"30776", "30776", "30777", "30777", "30777", "30778", "30778", 
"30779", "30780", "30780", "30780", "30781", "30782", "30782", 
"30783", "30784", "30785", "30786", "30787", "30788", "30788"
), Direction = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Marine", 
"River"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -164L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a venn diagram with a circle for each direction. Inside each circle is a number indicating the number of transmitters that are considered 'river', 'marine' or both.

This is some code I modified from a website:

```
install.packages('VennDiagram')
library(VennDiagram)

venn.diagram(
  x = list(
    lasts2WOFD %>% filter(Direction == 'Marine') %>% select(Transmitter) %>% unlist() , 
    lasts2WOFD %>% filter(Direction == 'River') %>% select(Transmitter) %>% unlist()
  ),
  category.names = c("Marine" , "Fresh"),
  filename = 'VennDiagram',
  output = TRUE ,
  imagetype="png" ,
  height = 480 , 
  width = 480 , 
  resolution = 300,
  compression = "lzw",
  lwd = 1,
  col=c("#440154ff", '#21908dff'),
  fill = c(alpha("#440154ff",0.3), alpha('#21908dff',0.3)),
  cex = 0.5,
  fontfamily = "sans",
  cat.cex = 0.3,
  cat.default.pos = "outer",
  cat.pos = c(-27, 27),
  cat.dist = c(0.055, 0.055),
  cat.fontfamily = "sans",
  cat.col = c("#440154ff", '#21908dff'),
  rotation = 1
)
```

When run, I get this error:

```
Error in VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = length(x[[1]]), area2 = length(x[[2]]),  : 
  argument 20 matches multiple formal arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question, I had a look at the source code of `VennDiagram` and I saw that `rotation` is part of `venn.diagram`, but not of `draw.pairwise.venn`. The parameter gets passed but cannot be used. Simply remove `rotation=1` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this does not answer your question, but I just wanted to let you know that you can get the diagram with other packages. My `nVennR` package can do that in a couple of steps. If your object is called `lasts2WOFD`,

```
>library(nVennR)
>myV <- plotVenn(list(River=subset(lasts2WOFD, Direction == "River")$Transmitter, Marine=subset(lasts2WOFD, Direction == "Marine")$Transmitter))
```

The result would be:

[image: Pairwise Venn diagram]

You can control the output as explained in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html). You can also export a vectorial `svg` file that you can edit afterwards.